# Argument of type 'string | number | string[] | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string' when converting JavaScript to TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

> I'm trying to covert the following JavaScript function to TypeScript and I'm getting the following error

```js
$("#checkoutSubmit").click(function () {
    var departureDate = $("#bookingDepartureDateInput").val();
  localStorage.setItem("datevalue", departureDate);
  console.log(localStorage.getItem("datevalue"))
});
```

[image: Error I get]

I've never used TypeScript and I seem to be struggling with converting this. Can I get some insight on how to rewrite this code in TypeScript? Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Please post code, error messages, markup, and other textual information **as text**, not as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the JQuery `val();` method can return a `String`, `Number` or `Array<string>` this causes an error because `localStorage.setItem` only accepts strings.

If you are sure that `$("#bookingDepartureDateInput").val();` always returns a string you can use `as string` to tell typescript that it can assume it will be a string:

```
$("#checkoutSubmit").click(function () {
  const departureDate = $("#bookingDepartureDateInput").val() as string;
  localStorage.setItem("datevalue", departureDate);
  console.log(localStorage.getItem("datevalue"))
});
```

JQuery `.val()` [docs.](https://api.jquery.com/val/)

Comment: Also, if you're learning TypeScript (and this applies to modern JavaScript too), it's time to start using `let` and `const` instead of `var`.

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery [`val` method](https://api.jquery.com/val/) returns `string`, `string[]`, `number`, or `undefined`. But you're trying to use it with the storage interface's `setItem` method, which only accepts strings. So you get an error, since that may be a mistake.

If you know that the value from `val` will be a string, while you **could** just do `as string` on it, the problem with that is you're making an assumption that you aren't checking: that nothing will make that claim (a *type assertion*) untrue. Instead, you could use a type assertion function to reassure TypeScript *and* ensure that the condition is correct:

```
function assertIsString(value: any): asserts value is string {
    if (typeof value !== "string") {
        throw new Error(`String expected, got non-string instead`);
    }
}
```

The the code would be:

```
$("#checkoutSubmit").click(function () {
    const departureDate = $("#bookingDepartureDateInput").val();
    assertIsString(departureDate);
    localStorage.setItem("datevalue", departureDate);
    console.log(localStorage.getItem("datevalue"))
});
```

That works because after the assertion function call, TypeScript knows it has a `string`.